# .htaccess small issue

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have a rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule   ^pages/(.+)$   info_pages.php?page_url=$1   [L]
```

this was working well Before.

my url like this but at localhost

http://dressgirls.com/demo2/pages/contact-us.html

this pointing to

http://dressgirls.com/demo2/info_pages.php

when i use this

```
echo $_GET['page_url'];
```

it gives me. `contact-us.html/contact-us.html/contact-us.html`

it should give `contact-us.html` one time only.

do you have idea what is wrong here.?

This is full code

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteRule   ^pages/(.+)$   info_pages.php?page_url=$1   [L]
 RewriteRule   ^reviews/(.+)$   edit_review.php?review_id=$1   [L]
 RewriteRule   ^deals/(.+)$   category.php   [L]
 RewriteRule   ^city/(.+)$   location_deals.php   [L]

 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} =-f
 #RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1.html [NC,L]
 #RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$  $1.php [NC,L]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)\.html$
RewriteCond %1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ deal-detail-page.php  [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change code to:

```
RewriteBase  http://dressgirls.com/
RewriteRule   ^pages/(.+)$   info_pages.php?page_url=$1   [L]
```

and try.